# Python Optional Match Groups

Tags: python, regex

I have the following that I need to place into match groups.

```
a = '1,2,3(1)'
b = '1,2,3'
```

parsing a is fine,

```
>>> m = re.match('^([0-9,-,\,]*)(\([0-9]*\))',a)
>>> m.groups()
('1,2,3', '(1)')
```

I  just need to confirm how to make the second match group optional so I can parse the variable b.

Comment: Tip: only one comma is needed: `[0-9,-\]*`

Comment: I think you just want `[0-9,]` as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
m = re.match('^([0-9,-,\,]*)(\([0-9]*\))?',a)

                                       ^^
```

This should do it for you